# WPF application with live XML feed

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xml-parsing

My brother asked me to develop an application for him, but I don't exactly know how to plan it.

It will be a WPF program with set of controls and I know how to make everything, except there should also be a datagrid and a bunch of labels and other controls **updated continously** with a XML feed from a server. Application will aproximately query and refresh the XML data every 2-5 seconds. I know there exist several methods to do that, but I would really choose the best one between quality and performance.

I've never done something like that before, so I'm here to ask what is the best approach for continous download of XML files, parsing them and putting the data into WPF controls?

Comment: It really depends how 'real time' you need the data to be, and how many users you are serving. Check out this example for comet with WCF, it has explanations of a couple of ways to do it with their pros and cons. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/186723/Push-Messages-in-RESTful-WCF-Web-Application-with

Comment: Number of users is not really a problem because the server hosting XML files is giant and super responsive. I can also use JSON instead of XML if there's any significant difference in performance.

Comment: @mot Server I use is a third party server and the XML/Json files are public available, so from my point it's just about to download them and parse the data. Just parsing is the problem I might have.

Comment: Parsing probably isn't the problem. How quickly do you need the XML file to be updated in all your clients? If they update automatically every couple of minutes, is that good enough?

Comment: @mot Let's say every 5 seconds. Is that a problem? I mean simultaneous updating of about 5 different XML files every 5 seconds.

Comment: So that is 5 files being served every 5 seconds, multiply that by the number of expected users and then you know how much load the server could take. Let's say it's not working magically if you are over a 1000 users at the same time. Sounds to me like polling (as explained in the link I added before) could do the trick.

Comment: @mot so basically I can setup the Comet service on a server which checks XML file every X seconds and sends packs of data to my application **only** when a change to initial file is made (XML file)?

Comment: Comet is for real time updates. In your case you could just download the xmls every 5 seconds. If you want a less data-pricy solution, you can have a page that just returns a latest version number for the files, and poll it from your client every 5 seconds, if the version number is bigger than the one in the client, download the xmls again.